# How to fix the height and width of image inside div generated dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

```
<div id="ARDiv" style="bottom: 10px; float: left; position: fixed; height:200px ; width:161px;">
 </div>
```

In this Div Images are shown one after the other using jquery

what i want to do is fix the height and width of the image so that it doesn't get bigger than

```
 height:200px ; width:161px;
```

**EDIT:**  This is just how my adrotator works-

`$("#ARDiv").adrotator({ intervalTime: 3000, xmlFileName: 'Adrotator.xml' });`

Comment: just write it as css :-) #ARDiv > img{max-width:161px, max-height:200px;}

Comment: how are you loading the next image jQuery? put height and width there in the jQuery where your are loading the image. or create a `css-class` with `ARDiv img`

Comment: it doesn't work tried that

Comment: @Bernhard will it be applied to the image which is loaded by the jQuery.

Comment: yes using jquery to show the next image

Comment: as said above just use max-width/height properties, they have pretty much good support http://caniuse.com/minmaxwh, though your question looks not clear, how adrotator related to max width/height?

Comment: @krshekhar yes off course each element matching the css selector will be formated as the corresponding stylesheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with css like so

```
#ARDiv img {
 height:200px ;
 width:161px;
}
```

or with jquery after you insert the image add this `.height(200).width(161);`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the size in css:

```
#ARDiv img{
    height: 200px;
    width: 161px;
}
```

^ this says that any image that appears inside the `#ARDiv` div will be fixed to those dimensions

or in jQuery: `$('#ARDiv').find('img').height('200px').width('161px');`